# CASE statement divided by another CASE statement gives value 0

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I am calculating ratio based on a Year and Month for each year. Both CASE statements bring correct values, that need to be divided. But for some reason I got 0 or -100

```
;WITH cte_yoyComparison
AS
        (
SELECT  Year(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveYear,
        Month(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveMonth,
        SUM(Premium) as Premium 
FROM    Test_Plaza_ProductionReport 
WHERE YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY      Year(EffectiveDate),
                Month(EffectiveDate)            
            )
SELECT *, b.YearNum,b.MonthNum,

            ((case when b.YearNum=2016 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium   end ))   /(case when b.YearNum = 2015 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium end)  as Ratio,
            ((((case when b.YearNum=2015 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium   else 0 end))   /NULLIF((case when b.YearNum = 2016 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium   else 0 end),0))-1)*100 as Ratio1,
            case when b.YearNum=2015 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium  else 0 end as CorrectValue,
            case when b.YearNum = 2016 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium else 0 end as CorrectValue1
 FROM tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN cte_yoyComparison a ON b.MonthNum=a.EffectiveMonth AND b.YearNum=a.EffectiveYear
WHERE b.YearNum<>2017
Order BY EffectiveYear desc,EffectiveMonth
```

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of  the `Premium` column ?

Comment: Int dividend by a larger int will produce a zero.  Cast either numerator or denominator to something with a decimal

Comment: I tried to CAST numerator as FLOAT, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to compare 2 rows not two columns, but are really comparing 1 column to 2 values.

```
((case when b.YearNum=2016 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium   end ))   /(case when b.YearNum = 2015 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium end)  as Ratio,
```

will always evaluate to `NULL / Premium` or `Premium / Null` because `b.YearNum` cannot be 2 values in the same row

```
((((case when b.YearNum=2015 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium   else 0 end))   /NULLIF((case when b.YearNum = 2016 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium   else 0 end),0))-1)*100 as Ratio1,
```

Will always evaluate to `0 / (Premium -1) * 100` OR `Premium / (-1 * 100)`

You are not comparing rows you are comparing columns and in this case the value of the same column to 2 different values.

Did you perhaps mean for one side of the division to be evaluated by looking at table `a` instead of `b`?

With only knowing what I can see in your queries leave your cte as is and just change your query from it to something like follows.  Note I did change your tblCalendar from a to c it makes more since to me being calendar starts with c.

```
SELECT *,
    ISNULL(a.Premium,0) / ISNULL(b.Premium,1) AS Ratio
FROM tblCalendar c  
    LEFT JOIN cte_yoyComparison a
    ON c.MonthNum=a.EffectiveMonth
    AND c.YearNum=a.EffectiveYear
    LEFT JOIN cte_yoyComparison b
    ON c.MonthNum=b.EffectiveMonth
    AND c.YearNum - 1 = b.EffectiveYear
WHERE
    c.YearNum<>2017
ORDER BY
    c.YearNum DESC
    ,c.MonthNum
```

What it does is self joins another copy of your cte but from 1 year less than the s.yearnum  Because you are using outer joins it will include all years etc. so if there isn't a match you need to handle the null value.  After that there is no need to compare any dates because you are guaranteed that table a will be 1 year newer than table b.

Comment: b table is a calendar table. I am using left join to get data for all months even if there are no data.  I added picture with data sample

Comment: Oleg you are comparing b.value = 2016 in the numerator and b.value = b.2015 in the denominator.  Only 1 of those conditions is going to be true per row. Which means you will always get ELSE part of at least one of your case statements.  Look at what I am telling you it will evaluate to which is what your description implied.  You need to work on your comparisons and maybe even enact a self join for the year over year.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any examples related to my problem?

Comment: I just updated with something that will probably work for you.  You are needing to compare 2 different rows but as columns a second join with different conditions essentially will give you the right data to calculate on.

Comment: It works. Thanks. The only thing I need three rows, first one compares values 2016 with 2015 which is you did. But is any chance second column would compare 2015 versus 2014 and the third one 2014 vs 2013

Comment: which database are you using?  sql-server, mysql, oracle, etc?  I will be offline for a while, but lookup how to PIVOT data.  turn the select I gave you into another cte and then PIVOT the data to get the 3 columns you want.

Comment: Matt, sorry for stupid question. It works for all years. I just need to figure out how to properly display it in SSRS.  Thank you very much. Honestly I would not be come up with this logic. Thanks man

Comment: oh ssrs, you can do do it directly there.  Look up Pivot SSRS I am sure you will find something helpful and it will probably be easier than in SQL directly.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have added `* 1.00` to your numerator which will essentially result in a decimal cast.

```
;WITH cte_yoyComparison
AS
        (
SELECT  Year(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveYear,
        Month(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveMonth,
        SUM(Premium) as Premium 
FROM    Test_Plaza_ProductionReport 
WHERE YEAR(EffectiveDate) <> 2017
GROUP BY      Year(EffectiveDate),
                Month(EffectiveDate)            
            )
SELECT *, b.YearNum,b.MonthNum,

            ((case when b.YearNum=2016 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium * 1.00  end ))   
                     /(case when b.YearNum = 2015 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium * 1.00 end)  as Ratio,
            ((((case when b.YearNum=2015 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium * 1.00  else 0 * 1.00 end))   
                      /NULLIF((case when b.YearNum = 2016 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium * 1.00  else 0 * 1.00 end),0))-1)*100 as Ratio1,
            case when b.YearNum=2015 and b.MonthNum=1 THEN Premium * 1.00  else 0 * 1.00 end as CorrectValue,
            case when b.YearNum = 2016 and b.MonthNum = 1 THEN Premium * 1.00 else 0 * 1.00 end as CorrectValue1
 FROM tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN cte_yoyComparison a ON b.MonthNum=a.EffectiveMonth AND b.YearNum=a.EffectiveYear
WHERE b.YearNum<>2017
Order BY EffectiveYear desc,EffectiveMonth
```

Now looking at your data, it is obvious that why are you not getting the desired result set. Your Join Condition says

```
  b.MonthNum=a.EffectiveMonth AND b.YearNum=a.EffectiveYear
```

Matching on Month and Year, yet in the case statement you are using `Numerator` and `denominator` from different years.

Your Case statement does exactly the opposite of what your join condition is doing, Hence the case statement never evaluates to true and you are getting all NULLS.

Comment: Now I got -100.0000000000

Comment: if you could add some sample data to your question it would help to see where are you going wrong.

Comment: (January 2016 value / January 2015 value) - 1

Comment: Should be simple, I dont know what am I doing wrong

Comment: I added a picture with data sample

Comment: guys look at my answer it isn't datatype it is his case statement is trying to evaluate the same column to 2 different values and expects to receive the THEN rather than ELSE portion of his statements.

Comment: @Matt True after looking at the data screenshot it is definitely the Wrong joins not the data type, `Money / Money` should yield `Money` data type which can accommodate decimals .